# Having trouble reading this formula

Tags: optimization

Please help me translating this formula to plain english. I have no idea whats happening here

$$
\{x^{(k)}\} \subset X, x^{(k)} \rightarrow x^* \in X \Rightarrow \liminf_{k\rightarrow\infty} f(x^{(k)}) \ge f(x^*)
$$

Thanks in advance

Comment: could you provide some context?

Comment: @cbs Apparently, it's about lower semi-continuity. Thats all I can really get out of it myself.